# How do I solve this differential equation ? It looks like just an integration problem.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$\dfrac{dy}{dx} = \dfrac{xy}{x +y}$$

I am finding this very hard to understand how this is a differential equation requiring solving, wouldn't you just integrate the function ?

Thanks.

Comment: You can't just "integrate the function" because the function $y$ appears both differentiated and not.

Comment: Coefficients are homogeneous, you can use $u=y/x$ transformation as well.

Comment: @user137035 But then on the right hand side you get $\dfrac{y}{1+u}$, don't you?

Answer (score 4):

As the comment says, as $y$ appears on both sides you can't just integrate. If it helps, write it as
$$
\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{x \cdot y(x)}{x + y(x)}
$$
How would you integrate that? It would be solving
$$
y(x) = \int \frac{x \cdot y(x)}{x + y(x)} dx
$$
for $y(x)$, which is not easier.